# Remote Screen Sharing between multiple instance of Windows Server 2003. Is it possible?

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, remote-desktop, bandwidth, remote-access

I am working on a project with my friends online as well as locally through connecting LAN.

I am using Windows Server 2003 that allows maximum 3 instances of remote desktop connections.

I have static Ip(when working on internet else local ip) through which all my team mates gets connected to my W2K3 instance and can work on their own desktop screen.

Now in this case all the 3 users are working on their own instances of desktop which is actually running on 1 system only, whether they are connect it online or on LAN.

But what happens sometimes is, if one of the user gets stucks at certain stage. Now i want to help him by checking his instance screen at my instance.

In this case all the 3 screens are situated at same system only. So I actually need not use internet for sharing screen as all the 3 instances are their only on the same system. 
So how would i access the other instance screen.

I need some such solution where i can minamize bandwidth(Internet) usage which a very very crucial for me at this point.
Any software or some method.

Client machines are connecting thru Windows XP.
Server Machine is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickest way to do this, is when you're both logged into the 2K3 server, to go to the Task Manager, go to the Users tab, right-click on the person you want to help, and click "Remote Control".

The other user will then be prompted to accept control, and once they've done it, you will both be operating in the same terminal session.

When you connect, it will ask you what you want to make your Escape sequence. Make sure you remember this (it's usually Control + Keypad *) as this is the keystrokes you will need to make to disconnect from the session and get back to your own.

Comment: thx i was looking for something like that only +100 from my side

Comment: If only you could give +100 ;)

Comment: I wish i could lol